# Owl Carousel: Run function when last slide is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to run a function when the last slide of the carousel has been reached. I've managed to use afterInit and afterMove callbacks to cycle the carousel items but I just need to be able to run a function when the cycle ends.

Hope you can help.

Plugin: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing

```
slideshow.owlCarousel({
            navigation: false, // Show next and prev buttons
            slideSpeed: 300,
            paginationSpeed: 400,
            singleItem: true,
            autoPlay: false,
            stopOnHover: false,
            afterInit : cycle,
            afterMove : moved,
        });

        function cycle(elem){
          $elem = elem;
          //start counting
          start();
        }

        function start() {
          //reset timer
          percentTime = 0;
          isPause = false;
          //run interval every 0.01 second
          tick = setInterval(interval, 10);
        };

        function interval() {
          if(isPause === false){
            percentTime += 1 / time;
            //if percentTime is equal or greater than 100
            if(percentTime >= 100){
              //slide to next item 
              $elem.trigger('owl.next')
            }
          }
        }

        function moved(){
          //clear interval
          clearTimeout(tick);
          //start again
          start();
        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't find any `onEnd` handler.

But you can use `afterMove` event to check if the displayed element is the last by accesing the carousel instance properties `currentItem` and `itemsCount`.

Ref:

> var owl = $(".owl-carousel").data('owlCarousel');

Code:

```
// carousel setup
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    navigation: false,
    slideSpeed: 300,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    singleItem: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    afterMove: moved,
});


function moved() {
    var owl = $(".owl-carousel").data('owlCarousel');
    if (owl.currentItem + 1 === owl.itemsAmount) {
        alert('THE END');
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/34bJ6/

Comment: I can't get this to work, but I am using owl carousel 2 beta...do you know if the same thing should work there?

Answer (score 6):

The above works (I suppose) on Owl Carousel 1, but if you are using the new Owl 2 beta you will need:

```
 $('.owl-carousel').on('change.owl.carousel', function(e) {
if (e.namespace && e.property.name === 'position' 
&& e.relatedTarget.relative(e.property.value) === e.relatedTarget.items().length - 1) {
// put your stuff here ...
console.log('last slide')
}
});
```

I got the above answer here btw: https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel2/issues/292#event-140932502

Comment: This works like a charm :)
Thanks Stephen
(I was having the same issueas Qbessi)

Comment: This works brilliantly if your using the beta version.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution, in my opinion:
(the code above doesn't take into account responsive layouts with a variable amount of items being shown at a time)

```
  mySlider.on('change.owl.carousel', function(e) {
    // number of items on screen updates on responsive
    var shown = e.page.size

    // total number of slides
    var total = e.relatedTarget.items().length - 1

    // current slide index
    var current = e.item.index

    // how many slides to go?
    var remain = total - (shown + current)

    if( !remain ){
      // last slide, fire a method - but dont forget to add checks that you only fire it or execute it once
    }
  });

  mySlider.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
    // am i the first slide? I do it this way so that we can check for first being true
    var first = ( !e.item.index)

    if( first ){
      // first slide, fire a method - but dont forget to add checks that you only fire it or execute it once
    }
  });
```

Comment: This is for me the clearest and the best, as take into account responsiveness and positions and also how many items are displayed. Previous options wont work if, for example, your number of items does not match with pages (ie slide by 5 and you have 7 elements). This one also works on Owl V2

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using the beta in 2016 the easiest way is to use the 'translated' event like so:-

```
// I'm using Drupal so I already have a carousel going.
var owl = $('#owl-carousel-page2');
// After slide has moved fire some stuff
owl.on('translated.owl.carousel', function (event) {
    console.log(event, "the event after move");
});
```

I've read a lot of ways of doing this but this seems to work the best fyi.

Answer (score 1):

i ran into same problem so i searched but these answers were not working for me, so here is my solution, which will work with multiple item slides and single item slide as well.

```
$('.owl-carousel').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
          if (e.page.index+1 == e.page.count) {
            console.log('last');
          }
          if (e.item.index==0) {
            console.log('start');
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above solutions don't work on Owl Carousel 2.3.4

So I had to figure out a way to do that and I ended up with the following solution

```
$('.owl-carousel').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {

    var items     = e.item.count;     // Number of items
    var item      = e.item.index;     // Position of the current item
    var size      = e.page.size;      // Number of items per page

    if (item === 0) {
        console.log('Start')
    }

    if ((items - item) === size) {
        console.log('Last')
    }
    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but I came with a simpler solution that covers both situations: multiple(customItems) and singleItem, just use it like this:

```
$('.wrap_carousel_feeds').owlCarousel({
    rewindNav: false,
    responsiveRefreshRate: 50,
    //singleItem: true, //works
    itemsCustom: [
        [2570, 15], [2390, 14], [2210, 13], [2030, 12], [1850, 11], [1670, 10], [1490, 9], [1310, 8], [1130, 7], [950, 6], [770, 5], [590, 4]
    ], //works too
    afterMove: function(owl){
        data = $(owl).data('owlCarousel');
        isLast = data.currentItem + data.visibleItems.length == data.itemsAmount;
        if(isLast){ //returns true when reaches the last
            //do stuffs
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rafaelmoni/1ty13y93/

Answer (score 0):

I am using owl carousel 2 and found out these variables might be able to help:

```
 $('.owl-carousel').on('change.owl.carousel', function(e) { 
   var carousel = e.currentTarget,
       totalPageNumber = e.page.count, // count start from 1
       currentPageNumber = e.page.index + 1; // index start from 0
   if(currentPageNumber === totalPageNumber - 1){
     console.log('last page reached!');
   }
  });
});
```

Slick carousel is a much better alternative to owl carousel. I would highly recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$carousel.on('change.owl.carousel', function (e) {
         if (e.namespace && e.property.name === 'position' && e.item.index === e.item.count - 1) {
              if (ko.isObservable(values.loaded)) {
                   values.loaded(false);
              }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See below:

```
$(".owl-carousel").on('change.owl.carousel', function(e) { 

    var total = e.item.count, // # of total items
    itemsPerPage = e.page.size, // # of items that appear per page
    itemGoOut = e.item.index, // index of last item that appeared then went out (index start with 0)
    itemRemain = total - (itemsPerPage + itemGoOut + 1);

    if(itemRemain === 0){
        console.log("No more Items");
    }

});
```