# JavaScript: Owl Carousel - stop slider at last slide

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

What I want to do:

I know the dimensions of every slide. I can access $(window).width() for the overall screen size. What I want to do, using this js:

https://jsfiddle.net/8mve0hjy/

is stop the slider once it has reached the edge of the window. I am aware of alternatives, such as: [Owl Carousel: Run function when last slide is reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112084/owl-carousel-run-function-when-last-slide-is-reached)

But I would like to use the JS i've provided as it is what is used in the module I'm using.

Alternatively, I am open to incorporating some function outside of this, that uses the classes `.owl-item` for each item, and `owl-wrapper` for the container.

What I have tried:

On line 365 I changed:

```
maximum = ((base.itemsAmount * base.itemWidth) - base.options.items * base.itemWidth) * -1;
```

to:

```
maximum = ((base.itemsAmount * base.itemWidth) - $(window).width()) * -1;
```

Comment: Your fiddle is merely the owl carousel code. Where is your code?!

Comment: Well, to be honest, I'm trying to look through the owl code and modify it to stop the slider. I will post what I have tried.

Comment: Your rationale is a little puzzling. What is it that you're trying to ultimately achieve? Why must you use that version of owl? Also, stop when *what* has reached *which* edge?

Comment: Yeah, I know this isn't great... okay so, I have to use this version, because it is what is available for using owl carousel with react with meteorJS. I am trying to stop the owl-wrapper (containing the owl-items) from translating it's x pixel distance farther than the max distance it should be (number of items * base.itemWidth). I am removing the window width because the original owl-wrapper width is the window's width.

Comment: A picture paints a thousand words. Why not add an image or simple demo (using SO's code snippets) to your question?

Comment: Haha, explaining helped me figure it out. I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

In addition to reseting the maximum, I also had to reset the max slide amount:

on line 1005:

```
maxSwipe = function() {
// return base.maximumPixels + base.newRelativeX / 5; // change to:
   return base.maximumPixels; // essentially, it stops it from going higher than the max allowed.
};
```